# How to migrate from C++ COM to C++CLI

Tags: c#, com, c++-cli

I have a C++ DLL that exposes stuff via COM.  I want to convert it to C++/CLI that exposes a managed interface.  Ideally I just add CLI and convert interfaces one by one.  So far I haven't succeeded in anything, so I'm looking for a specific strategy.

---

More detail:
A long time ago, I created an app using COM to communicate back and forth between C# and C++.  I'm sick of COM, and the registration and the hoop jumping needed on the C++ side.

I want to use C++/CLI, and get the whole thing working as managed code with the occasional call from C++/CLI to native libraries I'm using.

Can anyone suggest a gentle migration path, such that I can have both CLI and COM going, and convert things over class by class testing as I go?  Or something like that.

To be clear: I currently have native C++ code defining and implementing COM interfaces.  I have C# code using COM attributes to export classes.  All this stuff gets registered for COM interop, and there are calls in both directions.  I hope to switch the C++ to CLI and switch to managed classes in C++ rather than COM classes.

Question updated for Ramhound:  Anyway, I'm running into brick walls.  Turning on /clr on a C++ dll gives me link errors from other stuff trying to connect to that C++ code.  (Unreadable ATL/COM messages of the sort that drive me away from C++)

Comment: Update your question.  Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: There's nothing like "ideally" or "switching" for what you want to accomplish. It may be a lot of work. I understand this does not answer your question, but if COM registration is the main issue, you could switch to Registration-free COM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your input, Simon.  I was beginning to suspect that might be the case.  I'll check that out.

Comment: I haven't found a good answer to this question.  I found the Reg-Free COM to be flaky, and I want to get away from that sort of problem, into code that just works.  Consequently, though it's a lot of work, I'm porting over to strict C#.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read through this, as it provides some different approaches and considerations involved: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315414.aspx

Here is a simple example of how to use interop in C++/CLI, where you could define a method or two and add more as you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/borisj/interop-101-part-1

Comment: Thank you.  The first link is very informative, and gives good considerations.  In our case, performance is critical and the interop is basically passing access to C# objects.  The data is recieved from C# via COM; new objects are created by calling back through COM; and when the C++ function ends, all this COM stuff is dropped.  Now how can we introduce C++CLI?

Answer (score -1):

please follow this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163494.aspx

use tlimp to generate a COM unmanaged DLL to a managed DLL

is pretty simple!!!

Comment: Sorry that doesn't answer the question.  I already *have* a program that generates a managed interop DLL to connect to unmanaged COM.  I *want* to stop using COM entirely, and use C++/CLI instead.